# Remove destroy all instances after

Tags: java, list, arraylist, entity

So I have list

```
public List<Entity> entities;//initialized in constructor by entities  = new ArrayList<Entity>();
```

Whenever I do something like

```
entities.get(1).destroy();
```

It applies the method to every single entity of the same class(as in if I had the class slime destroy() would affect all the slimes but nothing else) in the list. Is there any way to fix this?

edit:I just did some testing. Apparently it only affects the entities after the first one affected in the array.

edit2: Okay more testing done and because of this you might as well ignore the whole above part. In an arraylist I have whenever I call remove(int i) it gets rid of the object at the location put in and all of the objects after it.

Comment: We need to see the `destroy()` method to be helpful. Are the entities in the list actually different instances of `Entity`?

Comment: Are you sure that all the "slime" variables are not referencing the same object? How do you create them?

Comment: You probably added the same entity several times to the list. Make sure the `new Entity()` is inside the loop filling the list, and not outside.

Answer (score 2):

Check whether all references in the lists are pointing to a single object.

When you assign a variable of type `A` to another one, only references are copied. The object stills unique. So, if you want to `destroy` some element, you should check that it has been created with `new`, as JB Nizet pointed out.

Comment: All the elements are created with new

Comment: @meme Ok. Look at the way they are added to the list. Are you sure every distinct element is being added? I think what is added is a single object of multiple references

Comment: No. they are not all the same object I checked

Comment: @meme Can we see the full code that creates the list, creates the objects, and adds them to the list?